# Unable to mount new volume on node

Tags: google-api, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

Hi im trying to mount a new volume for my db pod, i execute `kubectl describe pod rc-chacha-5064p` to see what its taking so long and i get the following

`FailedMount     AttachVolume.Attach failed for volume "db-xxxx-disk-pv" : googleapi: Error 403: Exceeded limit 'maximum_persistent_disks' on resource 'gke-xxxx-cluster-1-db-pool-xxxxx-xxxx'. Limit: 16.0`

is there a way to raise that limit, i already went trough ***google quotas*** but there is nothing about this kind of restriction, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This is not a quota issue but a node level limit. Using beta apis, you can  create a machine type which can mount more number of disks. See this https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#increased_persistent_disk_limits